# Resource to replicate/transfer a question to another community

Tags: feature-request, migration

Is there a Stack Overflow project (or request) that enable users to replicate (or transfer) a question to another community?

This resource would be useful on these scenarios:

1. Questions that have issues related to different communities (for example, IT questions could be related to development and security issues).
2. A user figures out after posting a question that there is a more appropriate community to post it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a SO project (or request) that enable users replicates (or transfers) a question to other community?

No, not that I'm aware of rather than the standard sites offered to migrate questions.

---

Always be sure to meet the policies of a site when posting a question and read in their help center.

The policies might differ, but will have mostly the same base to define what's a VLQ (very low quality) question.

---

If you're referring to your own questions consider to delete them, and post at another more appropriate SE site.

If you can't delete because you've got answers, maybe ask a moderator to move your question to the more appropriate SE site.

Comment: About the question in two communities what I was in mind is is just a single question (not duplicates ones), but at some way be visible to two or more communities. Of course, users could only use this feature from a certain reputation. Aware about migrate questions.

Comment: @gwarah no, you can't share the question between multiple communities. If it sits between two you have to pick one, or split it into two tailored questions if appropriate.